# Calculate difference between list elements and append higher value to dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

My sub-program generates the list like below.

```
x_list=[292, 314, 451, 454, 460, 464, 468, 476, 1231, 1441, 1445]
```

Basically, I have to calculate the difference between each elements and if difference > 10, I have to retain only large element with difference of previous one. i.e difference between

```
451 & 454 = 3

454 & 460 = 6

460 & 464 = 4

464 & 468 = 4

468 & 476 = 8

Total     = 25 (3+6+4+4+8)
```

Since the difference between each of these elements is less than 10, I have to retain only 476 with value 25 in dictionary.

My desired output is:

```
x_dict={292: 0, 314: 0, 476: 25, 1231: 0, 1445: 4}
```

Below is my program:

```
for elem in range(1,len(x_dict)):
    ii = 10
    print elem
    diff=x_dict[elem]-x_dict[elem-1]
    print diff
    if diff <= 10:
        if x_dict[elem] not in x_dict:
            new_index = x_dict[elem]
            ii = ii + diff
            print "ii : ", ii
            print "Index :", new_index
            x_dict.update({new_index: ii})
        else:
            value=x_dict.get(elem, None)
            value=value+diff
            print "Value is : ", value
            print "Index is : ", new_index
            x_dict[elem] = value
    else:
        if x_dict[elem-1] not in x_dict:
            new_index = x_dict[elem - 1]
            print "Out ", new_index
            x_dict.update({new_index: ii})
```

Comment: show first what you have tried??

Comment: Updated the post with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the offset zip trick and then think of the loop as a state machine

the state is the 2 bits of the 2 booleans `(b-a) ? 10` and `f`  'flag' that indicates a 'run' of `(b-a) <= 10`

the start is booted up in the initalization `o = [(x_list[0], 0)]`
and the end is patched up for the case that the list ends during a 'run' of `(b-a) <= 10`

it seemed natural to operate on a list in the loop rather than try to construct a dictionary dynamically

just cast the list of tuples to a dictionary at the end

```
x_list=[292, 314, 451, 454, 460, 464, 468, 476, 1231, 1441, 1445]

o, f, sm = [(x_list[0], 0)], 0, 0

for (a, b) in zip(x_list, x_list[1:]):

    if (b-a) > 10 and f == 0: 
        o.append((b, 0))
        sm = 0

    if (b-a) <= 10 and f == 0:
        f = 1
        o.pop()

    if (b-a) <= 10 and f == 1: 
        sm += b-a

    if (b-a) > 10 and f == 1: 
        o.append((a, sm))
        f, sm = 0, 0
        o.append((b, 0))

if (b-a) <= 10 and f == 1: 
    o.append((b, sm))

dict(o)
Out[268]: {292: 0, 314: 0, 476: 25, 1231: 0, 1445: 4}
```